# Retrieving objects from redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, local-storage

How to access Redux store when it is an object?
In Redux DevTools structure is:
[image]

In FC I'm trying to access it:

```
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.user.data);
```

But first there is a hint:
*Property 'user' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.ts(2339)* although the code is in .jsx.
console.log("user: " + user) shows [object Object].

Including it in `return (<h1>user: {user.firstName}</h1)` throws an error that *Objects are not valid as a React child*.

Also I would like to store user in local storage but it saves as [object Object]
`localStorage.setItem('user', user);`

Comment: post code not screenshots.

Comment: `user` is object. thats why it stores as object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do `console.log("user", user)` to see the `user` object instead of `[Object object]` and to save it to the `localStorage` you need to convert it to a string ([read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)) like this

```
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
```

and to retrive it

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

The error you are getting on

```
return (<h1>user: {user.firstName}</h1>) // Here you missed a ">" in the question
```

is because inside the `user` object there is a property called `firstName` that is and object instead of a string, but we can't be sure because you cut that in the screen.